# "Mögen", "gefallen", "erfreuen" - was sagt man zu gutem Essen?

Tags: word-choice

When you want to say that you like a particular food or dish to eat, which do you say:

> *Ich mag die Suppe*;
>   *Die Suppe gefällt mir*; and/or
>   *Die Suppe erfreut mich*?

Or other?

Does it matter whether you have actually tried the food at one time or not?  (Like, if you saw a picture of a dish that you had never tried but you like the look of it.)

Answer (score 6):

The first version is ok, the other 2 are not.

> Die Suppe gefällt mir.

That sounds to me as if you like the sight of the soup, but that might be personal opinion. In either case it does not refer to the taste.

> Die Suppe erfreut mich

This, while not wrong, sounds like you're stage acting a piece of the 18th century to me.

The 2 most common ways to express that a meal is good are:

> Die Suppe schmeckt mir / gut (hervorragend, ausgezeichnet).
>
> Die Suppe ist gut (same words)

Comment: So if one has not tasted the dish yet, but would like to based on how good a photo of the dish looks, wouldn't one say:  Die Suppe gefaellt mir; or maybe Die Suppe sieht gut aus?

Comment: @ARoggen Yes, you are right. Also common would be 'Die Suppe ist hübsch/schön' or 'Die Suppe sieht hübsch/schön aus' but 'hübsch' is a word more common used by girls then boys. To say that it tastes good, 'Die Suppe ist lecker.' is very common as well.

Comment: Ich hab noch nicht verstanden, inwiefern "Die Suppe erfreut mich" nicht falsch sein soll. Kannst du mir einen Kontext geben, in dem dieser Satz angebracht wäre?

Comment: Im Theater oder beim Hochadel :)

Comment: Basiert die Projektion des Satzes ins 18. Jhr. auf guter Kenntnis der Sprache jener Zeit? Gibt es dafür einen Beleg? @NabilA. "Die Suppe ist hübsch/schön" würde man m.E. nicht sagen, weil dies mehr nach dem äußeren geht, ob sie fürs Auge schön hergemacht ist (außer das war die Frage). Ich habe die Frage so verstanden, ob man erwartet, dass sie schmecken wird, basierend auf einem Bild. Also wenn man mir 4 Suppen zur Wahl auf einem Bild zeigt, dann kann ich auf eine deuten und sagen "Die Suppe gefällt mir!". Und: Mädchen sagen häufiger "hübsch" als Jungs? Gibt es dafür einen Beleg?

Comment: Es basiert auf meinem Eindruck der Sprache jener Zeit. Es gibt keinen Beleg und ich habe auch keine Lust einen zu suchen. Schlage einen Edit vor, wenn es dich so stört.

Answer (score 5):

I think, if you did not taste the food before, you can't tell if you like it. You just can tell if you would like to try it. If you want to say something like this in German, use this phrases:

> Ich würde diesen Salat gerne mal kosten. (I would like to try this salad.)
>   Dieser Fisch schaut gut aus. (This fish looks fine)
>   Dieser Fisch sieht gut aus. (same as above)
>   Ich glaube, ich probiere mal einen Löffel von dieser Suppe. (I think, I'll try a spoonful of this soup)

When you did eat the food, you can tell if you like it in this way:

> Dieser Salat ist sehr gut. (This salad is very fine)
>   Dieser Fisch schmeckt sehr gut. (This fish tastes very fine)
>   Diese Suppe ist/schmeckt sehr lecker. (This soup is/tastes very delicious)

btw: "lecker" is not very common in Austria. For tourists it is ok to say "Dieser Käsekuchen war sehr lecker", but austrian People don't say that. They say "Diese Topfentorte war sehr gut". (Both is in english: "this cheesecake was very fine")

Comment: In [Namibia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache_in_Namibia) `lecker` is very common and it has the meaning _good_ - Not only for food.

Answer (score 2):

In case we want to order a *"particular"* dish we just say:

> Ich möchte gerne **dieses** Gericht [probieren].

In this case we put emphasis on a particular not further specified dish (e.g. *"Braten"*, *"Suppe"*, *"Nachspeise"*) by using *"dieses"*, and we do express we like it with *"gerne"*. In case we never had the dish before we can say so with the verb *"probieren"*. In case the name of the dish is known to us it is better to say:

> Ich möchte gerne den Rheinischen Sauerbraten. Ich hätte gerne eine Schwarzwälder Kirschtorte.

To communicate our favourite dish or drink we may use e.g.:

> Mein Leibgericht ist Kaiserschmarrn. Mein Lieblingsgetränk ist Coca Cola. Ich trinke Kaffee für mein Leben gerne. Besonders mag ich Bayrisches Kraut. [...]

After we tasted the food we may want to say how we liked it. This can be done in various ways:

> Dein Apfelkuchen hat gut geschmeckt. Ich mag die Suppe, die Deine Schwester immer kocht. Ich mochte besonders die Fischplatte, die es zu Silvester gab.

Also we can use *"gefallen"* in the context of food. Then we often not only judge the taste but also the overall experience we had. Therefore the usage of *"gefallen"* is more often used in a high class restaurant, in hotel reviews, or when we are being asked from a waiter.

> Wie hat Ihnen unser Essen gefallen?
>   Das Dessert hat uns leider nicht so gefallen. Es hat zwar ordentlich geschmeckt, war aber sehr lieblos dekoriert.
>   Das Essen im Hotel Schwanen hat uns sehr gefallen.

From a waiter in a standard restaurant you may however more often hear

> Wie hat es Ihnen geschmeckt?

Comment: +1 especially for mentioning *mögen*, which the other answers didn't mention, but is the first translation for *like*, especially when referring to food, I would think of...

Comment: Weitere Möglichkeiten für die Bestellung: "Für mich darf es ... sein", "Ich bekomme bitte ...", "Die [Nummer des Essens]"

Comment: @oregonGhost: mögen is ok but it is not the best choice to show immediate appreciation... it is more of a general statement for instance if you like the pizza at a particular place and you've had it several times already. Don't get me wrong. I am not totally opposing mögen, it is just not the most common phrasing in German

Comment: Die Antwort geht glaube ich ziemlich an der Frage vorbei.

Comment: @userunknown: nun ja, ich bin wie Du auch der Auffassung (mein erster Absatz!), dass hier in erster Linie danach gefragt wurde, wie man ein Essen bestellt. *"To like a particular food"*, die in der Frage genannten Beispiele, wie auch der usprüngliche Ttitel (*"(etwas zum essen)"*) und die anderen Antworten lassen aber durchaus auch eine allgemeinere Interpretation zu.

Comment: @Takkat: Mir ist unklar, wieso Du von der Suppe zum Gericht wechselst, und dann nicht mehr "die" sagen kannst, sondern "dieses" sagen musst, und dann "dieses" fett machst.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man ein Gericht auswählen soll, und nicht nachträglich dessen Geschmack bewertet, ist die simpelste Form:

> Ich möchte die Suppe.

In der gepflegten Konversation wird man eher sagen `Bitte bringen Sie mir die Suppe` oder `Bitte geben Sie mir etwas von der Suppe` oder eine der Formulierungen Huberts wählen - im informellen Kontext, an der Würstchenbude, auf der privaten Grillparty, zuhause ist "ich möchte die Suppe" passend. Alternativen: "Ich nehme die Suppe", "ich nehme von der Suppe".

Auf die Frage "Möchten Sie von der Suppe oder einen Salat?" kann man auch durchaus

> Die Suppe gefällt mir

antworten. Dies alles unter der Annahme, dass man sich auf den Namen, die Zutaten oder ein Bild stützt und eine Wahl trifft.

Comment: An der Würstchenbude hört man gerne auch nur *"Einmal Currywurst mit Pommes rot-weiß!"* (ohne *bitte*) ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Oder vielmehr *Schranke* ;)

Comment: Da gibt es sogar Videotutorials zu, `Imbißdeutsch`: "Nein ich bin das Schaschlik und er ist die Pommes." [5 Lektionen in 2 Minuten] (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECWoPwPK864) - @Takkat: Lt. Lesson 1 "Zwei Bratwurst bitte", also schon mit bitte. "listen and repeat".

Answer (score 2):

When you see a mouthwatering dish or any other yummy-looking ready-to-eat food (in real life or on TV/a photo), you say e.g.

> «Diese Suppe *sieht* | **köstlich / lecker / wunderbar** | *aus*.»  
>   (This soup *looks* |delicious/yummy/tasty/wonderful|.)

Or, you exclaim something like

> «Oh, wie | **köstlich / lecker** | !» 
>   (Ooohh, tasty!)

To praise a dish/food *after* having sampled it, you use the verb *schmecken* (to taste) or *sein* (to be) with them:

> «Die Suppe | **schmeckt / ist | köstlich**.» 
>   or simply: «Diese Suppe **schmeckt (sehr) gut**.»

To combine this with a request for that dish, e.g.

> «Ich hätte gerne |einen Teller / eine Terrine / eine Portion| dieser
>   köstlich aussehenden Suppe, bitte»
>  (I'd like to have a
>   plate/cup/portion of this delicious-looking soup, please.)

To express a craving for a dish that you're gaping at on the TV, in a magazine, through the shop windows of some fast-food eatery, or in you imagination:

> «Ich hätte jetzt so gerne einen Teller dieser |leckeren/lecker
>   aussehenden| Suppe.»
>  (I'd would love a plate of this
>   delicious-looking soup, if only I could have one.)
>
> «Ich hätte so gerne eines dieser |köstlichen/köstlich aussehenden|
>   Grillhähnchen.»
>  (das Grillhähnchen (singular) / die Grillhähnchen
>   (plural) = rotisserie chicken, usually sold by the half)
>
> «Ich hätte jetzt so gerne einen Döner mit Krautsalat, Tzaziki und
>   scharfer Sauce.»
>  (Turkish-style kebap with cabbage salad in a pita
>   bread topped with  yogurt-and-garlic sauce and a red hot sauce of
>   chopped tomatoes, onions and green pepper)
>
> «Ich hätte jetzt so gerne ein Stück von dieser |köstlichen/köstlich
>   aussehenden| Torte.»
>  (a piece of that wonderful torte)
>  ...

To simply state that you generally like a specific dish, use the verb 'mögen' (to like). If you're very passionate about it, use 'lieben' (to love).

> «Ich mag Pommes mit Mayo.»
>  
>   «Ich liebe Grünkohl und Pinkel.»

In comparison:

> Ich *mag* Grünkohl *lieber als* Pommes mit Mayo.
>  ('lieber' is not a
>   verb here, but a comparative form of the adjective 'lieb', which is
>   used for comparisons where personal preference is expressed.)